# can I use mysql with .net application ....or its only supposed to be used with php

Tags: mysql

Can mysql be with .net applications ....or its only supposed to be used with php.If yes can it support large applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use MySQL with .NET applications. [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.0.html) is an ADO data provider for MySQL that lets you access MySQL databases like any other database in .NET.

It can support large applications, yes. Of course, it depends on your definition of "large" but unless you're as big as Facebook, say, then you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is one of many DBMS systems that can be used with pretty much any front end application you can write in any language or framework. As long as their are drivers in your target language you can use MySQL as your backing data store.

MySQL is often used with PHP, along with Apache as the front end web server run on the Linux OS, the three together known as the "LAMP" stack. This is often the most economic combination of systems as all are free and open source.